# Batch update using PUT - wcf data services / odata

Tags: c#, java, odata, wcf-data-services-client

I have a java odata service which uses PUT to update data. Client is in dotnet.

I have an object (order) which has an attribute "list object" (order details).

Is it possible to send Order object in one short with order details list using below command

```
Order orderObj = new Order

OrderDetail oDetailObj = new OrderDetail 

context.AttachTo(Orders, orderObj);

Code to set properties of orderObj 

for loop to add orders details
{

Code to set properties of oDetailObj 

context.AddRelatedObject(orderObj, "OrderDetailsList", oDetailObj); 

}

DataServiceResponse response = context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

While running this code, only last order detail infomration is submitting to server. I have verified that using fidller

if you have any alternative please suggest.

Comment: Can you post more code as the 'context.SaveChanges' doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Put more code as requested

Comment: Can somebody help me :(